# Get list of all gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

What ever happend to **Rails.configuration.gems** in Rails 3? I guess it has to do with Bundler. But how can I find all gems now?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it has to do with Bundler. In Rails 3 your application's gem manifest is in a file called `Gemfile`. Some good explanations on the changes and how to use them [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/201-bundler), [here](http://vimeo.com/9282967), [here](http://www.railsdispatch.com/posts/bundler) and [here](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/07/26/whats-new-in-bundler-1-0-0-rc-1/).

**UPDATE**:

The `bundle show` CLI lists the gems in use by your application. But, programmatically you can get to the same thing as follows:

```
require 'bundler'
mygems = Bundler.load.specs.map { |spec| spec.name }
```

The spec object also contains other attributes of interest.

Comment: I have used Bundler a bit for Rails 3 apps, that I know how to do. But how do I from ruby code check stuff, such as this, find all gems for my application? Thats my problem...

Comment: I looked at the Bundler source and came up with something like this: Bundler.environment.dependencies.select { |d| d.groups.include?(:default) }.collect(&:name)

Not perfect though...

Comment: @rejeep Sorry I misunderstood you question the first time. I've added an update above which hopefully is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thats more like it! :) But, what I really want is the gems that was specified directly, excluding dependencies...

Comment: @rejeep Then in that case I can't think of any better way than just opening and reading all the `gem` lines in your Gemfile